# Finite difference mixed derivatives on quadrilateral (non-orthogonal) grids

Tags: finite-difference

Could someone tell, please, has someone constructed finite difference mixed derivatives on quadrilateral (non-orthogonal) grids, already? Without using aconformal mapping to an orthogonal grid. I mean we have the mixed differential operator and try to represent it through a difference relation.

I searched with the help of Google Scholar, but found nothing.

I tried to constuct it myself, but have problems with the symmetry of mixed second difference derivative: $$ f_{xy} = f_{yx} $$

Comment: Are you using regularly spaced grids?